# Does this declaration really change the meaning as the error says?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, using

Here is my code:

```cpp
namespace ns {
    
template<typename T>
struct Utility {
};

struct Concrete {
    using Utility = Utility<Concrete>;  
};

}
```

I have a template class `ns::Utility` and a class `ns::Concrete` that specifies the class for the utility: `ns::Concrete::Utility`. Now it should be possible to use the utilities that the concrete classes specialize for themselves.

That works for MSVC, but the GCC produces an error:

> error: declaration of ‘using Utility = struct ns::Utility’
> [-fpermissive] using Utility = Utility;
>
> error: changes
> meaning of ‘Utility’ from ‘struct ns::Utility’ [-fpermissive]

To fix that I can specify the namespace explicitly disambiguing the `ns::Concrete::Utility` and `ns::Utility`:

```cpp
namespace ns {
    
template<typename T>
struct Utility {
};

struct Concrete {
    using Utility = ns::Utility<Concrete>;  
};

}
```

But actually I don't see neither ambiguity nor any other problem in my initial code that should make the compiler complaining. I don't want to specify explicitly the full class name with the namespace as well: that makes the code less flexible (for example, what if I decide to rename the namespace?)

What does the standard say, and should my code be considered as an error?

**Update:** The advice to use `using Utility = ::Utility<Concrete>;` doesn't work (as there could be both `::Utility` and `ns::Utility`), and I still have to fully specify the type including namespace. So I can agree that g++ tries to avoid the case when both definitions are used in the same class, before and after `using`/`typedef`, but the need to fully specify the class name is very annoying. Moreover, even if I specify the full name, g++ has to produce an error in this case:

```cpp
struct Concrete {
    Utility<int> u1;
    using Utility = ns::Utility<Concrete>;  
    Utility u2;
};
```

Why does it care of a valid redefinition where I don't use both `Concrete::Utility` and `ns::Utility` in the same scope using the same `Utility` name?

Comment: gcc is right. So is clang, because a diagnostic is not required. And you don't have to use `ns::` explicitly. Just `using Utility = ::Utility<Concrete>;` works.

Comment: @cigien [a relatively recent similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61455507/hiding-names-with-using-directive) was answered as that it is gcc's bug and people seem to like the answer :/

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Well, that's annoying. I wonder what the protocol is for completely opposite answers to basically the same question. Merging seems weird. I assume that given this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63369264/is-a-nested-alias-template-that-redeclares-the-same-name-valid) we had, you disagree with the answer below.

Comment: @cigien: Using `using Utility = ::Utility<Concrete>;` doesn't work, you have to specify the namespace as well.